# Masked input failed on second ajax call using fucalendar

Tags: ajax, fullcalendar, mask

Good evening everyone,

I can not understand why my function does not work.
In a calendar made with fullcalendar (https://fullcalendar.io/)
when I double click on an appointment (fc-event) a div appears with an input field of type mobile num. The first double-click call does the job: the field is typed numerically, but if I re-double clicks on another appointment, the div gets updated with the right data but the input field mobile type is not typed numeric and the user can type letters in the field ...
How to do ?

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view)         // Modify month et week view.
        {
            // Double click
            element.on('dblclick', function() {
                var idmed = event.idmed;
                var idpat = event.idpat;
                var title = event.title;
                var form_data = {'title': title, 'idmed' : idmed, 'idpat' : idpat};
                $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: pageurl+"agenda/rdv_exist/",
                        data:  form_data,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(response)
                        {
                            $('body').append(response.data);
                        }
                    }).done(function() {
                            $.mask.definitions['~'] = '[67]';
                            $('#Mob').mask('0~.99.99.99.99',{placeholder:'-'});
                        }
                    );
                    return false;
            });
        },
```

Comment: your success routine is appending response.data to the body; is #Mob in that?  If Mob already exists the second time the ajax is called, calling the mask() function a second time would cause a problem like this.

Comment: why are you using both "success" and "done" separately with your ajax call? One or the other should be used, since they serve the same purpose. I'm not sure whether it's actually defined which one of them would be executed first.

Comment: Also, every time you run "append" you keep adding more form data to the page, but I don't see where you are removing it? Are you ending up with multiple fields with the same ID? And what exactly is the content of `response.data`? We don't quite have enough info to figure this one out.

Comment: @Brian Mains : Well seen ! Indeed, adding multiple ID = "Mob" creates the error. I must delete the item if it exists before and it works perfectly. Thank you so much
@ ADsyon : I didn't know that "succes" and "done" was the same. I would take success .. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Work fine:

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view)         // Modify month et week view.
    {
        // Double click
        element.on('dblclick', function() {
            var idmed = event.idmed;
            var idpat = event.idpat;
            var title = event.title;
            var form_data = {'title': title, 'idmed' : idmed, 'idpat' : idpat};

            $('#Mob').remove();

            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: pageurl+"agenda/rdv_exist/",
                    data:  form_data,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(response)
                    {
                        $('body').append(response.data);

                        $.mask.definitions['~'] = '[67]';
                        $('#Mob').mask('0~.99.99.99.99',{placeholder:'-'});
                    }
                });
                return false;
        });
    },
```